# Implementing captcha to my dynamically generated forms

Tags: php, sql

I have some functions that generate the articles on my page + the comments associated with them:

```
function comment_form($id) { // generates a comment box form for every article on the page
    global $user_data;

    if (logged_in() === true) {
        echo "
        <form method='post' action='' class='comments_form'>
            <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='your name... *' id='name' value='{$user_data['username']}'>
            <div class='captcha'>" . create_captcha() .  "</div> 
            <textarea name='comments' id='textarea' placeholder='your comment... *' cols='30' rows='6'></textarea>
            <input type='hidden' name='blog_id' value='$id'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='post' value='post'>
        </form>
        <hr class='artline'>";
    }
}

function list_articles($rows) { 
    if (empty($rows)) {
        return "There are no Articles to display";
    }

    $previous_blog_id = 0; 
    $content = '';

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($previous_blog_id != $row['content_id']) { // the blog id changed
            if ($previous_blog_id != 0) { // not the first section, close out the previous section
                $content .= comment_form($previous_blog_id); 
            }
            // start a new blog section
            $content .= "<h5 class='posted_by'>Posted by {$row['posted_by']} on {$row['date']}</h5>
                        <h1 class='content_headers'>{$row['title']}</h1>
                        <article>{$row['content']}</article>
                        <hr class='artline'>";
            $previous_blog_id = $row['content_id'];
        }
        if (!empty($row['comment_by']) && !empty($row['comments'])) {
             $content .= "<div class='commented_by'>User: {$row['comment_by']} </div>
                   <div class='comments'>Comment: {$row['comments']}</div>
                   <hr class='artline2'>";
        }
    }

    if ($previous_blog_id != 0) { 
        $content .= comment_form($previous_blog_id); 
    }

    return $content;
}

function insert_comments($comments, $comment_by, $blog_id) {
    include('core/db/db_connection.php');

    $comment_by = sanitize($comment_by);
    $comments = sanitize($comments);
    $blog_id = (int)$blog_id;
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO article_comments (
               comments, 
               comment_by, 
               blog_id
        )
        VALUES (
              '$comments', 
              '$comment_by', 
              '$blog_id'
        )
    ";

    mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
}
```

I generate a simple math captcha like per below:

```
function generate_captcha($num1, $num2) { // generates 2 random numbers
    $num1 = (int)$num1;
    $num2 = (int)$num2;
    $rand_num_1 = mt_rand($num1, $num2);
    $rand_num_2 = mt_rand($num1, $num2);
    $result = $rand_num_1 + $rand_num_2;

    return $result;
} 

function create_captcha() { // displays captcha on the page
    $num1 = generate_captcha(1, 20);
    $num2 = generate_captcha(1, 20);

    echo  $num1 . ' + ' . $num2 . ' = ';
    echo '<input type="text" name="captcha_results" size="2">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name=\'num1\' value=' . $num1 . '; ?>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name=\'num2\' value=' . $num2 . '; ?>';
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the `create_captcha()` function into my `comment_form()` function because I want every comment box to have a captcha associated with it. The same way every article has it's own comment box.

The above code is displaying a captcha field for each comment box I have, which is what I want. However - it moves all the comment boxes above the content making it look something like this:

```
|-------------------------------------| // comments form for article 1
|Name: New User                       |
|Comment: New comment !               |
|                                     | 
|-------------------------------------|
[Submit] [captcha field]

|-------------------------------------| // comments form for article 2
|Name: New User                       |
|Comment: New comment !               |
|                                     | 
|-------------------------------------|
[Submit] [captcha field]

Article_1 title: LOREM IPSUM
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
-------------------------------------- //comments
Name: User0
Comment: Great article!
--------------------------------------
Name: User1
Comment: Great article! - 2nd comment 
-------------------------------------- // end comments

============================================================

Article_2 title: LOREM IPSUM
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
-------------------------------------- //comments
Name: User0
Comment: Great article!
--------------------------------------
Name: User1
Comment: Great article! - 2nd comment 
-------------------------------------- // end comments
```

The behavior I am expecting is this:

```
Article_1 title: LOREM IPSUM
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
-------------------------------------- //comments
Name: User0
Comment: Great article!
--------------------------------------
Name: User1
Comment: Great article! - 2nd comment 
-------------------------------------- // end comments
|-------------------------------------| // comments form for article 1
|Name: New User                       |
|Comment: New comment !               |
|                                     | 
|-------------------------------------|
[Submit] [captcha field]

============================================================

Article_2 title: LOREM IPSUM
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
-------------------------------------- //comments
Name: User0
Comment: Great article!
--------------------------------------
Name: User1
Comment: Great article! - 2nd comment 
-------------------------------------- // end comments
|-------------------------------------| // comments form for article 2
|Name: New User                       |
|Comment: New comment !               |
|                                     | 
|-------------------------------------|
[Submit] [captcha field]
```

Is it something to do with the position in which I'm inserting the `generate_captcha` function that causes the comment boxes to float above content?

**EDIT:** If I return the form instead of echoing it - this works. The comment forms are placed below the correspondent articles:

```
function comment_form($id) {
    global $user_data;
    if (logged_in() === true) {
        return <<<EOT
        <form method='post' action='' class='comments_form'>
            <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='your name... *' id='name' value='{$user_data['username']}'>
            <textarea name='comments' id='textarea' placeholder='your comment... *' cols='30' rows='6'></textarea>
            <input type='hidden' name='blog_id' value='$id'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='post' value='post'>
        </form>
        <hr class='artline'>
EOT;
```

However, I cannot insert a function because of the `<<<EOT` I had to use. How can I insert the `create_captcha` function into the above??

**EDIT 2:** This will not return the expected captcha form, but it seems to place the comment forms in their place...

```
function comment_form($id, $captcha) { 
    global $user_data;
    if (logged_in() === true) {
        return <<<EOT
        <form method='post' action='' class='comments_form'>
            <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='your name... *' id='name' value='{$user_data['username']}'>
            <textarea name='comments' id='textarea' placeholder='your comment... *' cols='30' rows='6'></textarea>
            <input type='hidden' name='blog_id' value='$id'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='post' value='post'>
        </form>
        <hr class='artline'>
EOT;
    }
}

function list_articles($rows) {
    if(empty($rows)){
        return "There are no Articles to display";
    }

    $create_blog_captcha = create_blog_captcha();
    $previous_blog_id = 0; 
    $content = '';

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if ($previous_blog_id != $row['content_id']) { // the blog id changed
            if($previous_blog_id != 0) { // not the first section, close out the previous section
                $content .= comment_form($previous_blog_id, $create_blog_captcha); 
            }
            // start a new blog section
            $content .= "<h5 class='posted_by'>Posted by {$row['posted_by']} on {$row['date']}</h5>
                        <h1 class='content_headers'>{$row['title']}</h1>
                        <article>{$row['content']}</article>
                        <hr class='artline'>";
            $previous_blog_id = $row['content_id'];
        }
        if (!empty($row['comment_by']) && !empty($row['comments'])) {
             $content .= "<div class='commented_by'>User: {$row['comment_by']} </div>
                   <div class='comments'>Comment: {$row['comments']}</div>
                   <hr class='artline2'>";
        }
    }

    if($previous_blog_id != 0){ 
        $content .= comment_form($previous_blog_id, $create_blog_captcha); 
    }

    return $content;
}

function create_blog_captcha() { 
    $num1 = generate_captcha(1, 20);
    $num2 = generate_captcha(1, 20);
    $captchanum = $num1 . ' + ' . $num2 . ' = ';
    $captchanum .= '<input type="text" name="captcha_results" size="2">
                   <input type="hidden" name=\'num1\' value=' . $num1 . '>
                   <input type="hidden" name=\'num2\' value=' . $num2 . '>';
    return $captchanum;
}
```

How can I return the values of create_blog_captcha? I'm obviously doing it wrong...

Comment: you should be able to position these boxes where ever you like - check your css!

Comment: These are dynamically generated and the CSS is optimized for that only. When a user posts a new article, a comment form will be generated below that article. If I remove the `create_captcha` function from the comment form, I get the behavior I expect. So I don't believe this is a css problem. I think it has to do with the way I am inserting the  `create_captcha` function into the `comment_form` function, but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 2):

In the function  create_captcha() you have not closed the hidden input fields so you break the entire flow of the document.

```
function create_captcha() {
    $num1 = generate_captcha(1, 20);
    $num2 = generate_captcha(1, 20);

    return $num1 . ' + ' . $num2 . ' = 
    <input type="text" name="captcha_results" size="2">
    <input type="hidden" name=\'num1\' value=' . $num1 . ' />
    <input type="hidden" name=\'num2\' value=' . $num2 . ' />';
}
```

As you noted, the function previously echoed the content rather than return as a string to the other function that was utputting the html.

Comment: Ah ! I hoped that would work, seemed like the correct approach. However I still get the exact same behavior as before. Comment boxes are floated above article content

Comment: If the flow of the html looks correct in source view then I say it must be a css issue if the hidden fields are now closed correctly.

Comment: I've noticed that the issue has to do with the fact that I'm echoing the form. Please see my updated question

Comment: well spotted... return the string from the create_captcha() function